# Is there a way to access an android room database via console SQL commands?

Tags: android, sql, console, android-room

I'd like to eventually write independent SQL files to modify the database.  For now I am simply trying to get a linux console to access the database.  I am using the standard android studio emulator.

Comment: use [sqlite3](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3) tool

Comment: I got sqlite3 to work.  This helped a lot: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3